# How to show (1-15) of 50 records on a page using jquery pagination

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, simplepager

I'm using the jquery ui simplePagination plugin, and I'm trying to display the number of current record on the page.

I have something like this:

[image]

The feature I'm trying to achieve here is the 'Showing 1-15 of 50' ( these are the items on one page and 50 is the total number of items in the json object).

Here is how I implemented the above attached feature using jquery simplepagination:

```
var items = $("table tbody tr");
var numItems = items.length; //total items
var perPage = 10; //per page
var startindex = 15;
totalPages = ceil(numItems / perPage);
currentPage = ceil(startindex / perPage);
items.slice(perPage).hide();
$(".pagination-page").pagination({
    items: numItems,
    itemsOnPage: perPage,
    cssStyle: "light-theme",
    onPageClick: function (pageNumber) {
        var showFrom = perPage * (pageNumber - 1);
        var showTo = showFrom + perPage;

        items.hide().slice(showFrom, showTo).show();
    }
});
```

With the above code I can get the `<prev> and <next>` buttons to work and display the records accordingly.  However, I'm not able to figure out how can I display the current record range (1-15) using jquery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should helps you [http://plnkr.co/edit/3elrtkqzChAnHCal9Fg1?p=preview](http://plnkr.co/edit/drG3ftPoBS0KdZ27jsBe?p=preview)

JS:

```
   $(function() {
  var items = $("table tbody tr");
  var numItems = items.length-1; //total items
  var perPage = 3; //per page
  var startindex = 0;
  totalPages = Math.floor(numItems / perPage);
  currentPage = Math.ceil(startindex / perPage);
  $('.pagination-info').text("from " + (startindex + 1) + " to " + (perPage * (startindex + 1)));


  items.slice(perPage + 1).hide();
  $(".pagination-page").pagination({
    items: numItems,
    itemsOnPage: perPage,
    cssStyle: "light-theme",

    onPageClick: function(pageNumber) {

      var showFrom = ((pageNumber-1)  * perPage)+1;
      var showTo = (showFrom + perPage) ;

      $('.pagination-info').text("from " + (showFrom) + " to " + ((showTo-1)>numItems ? numItems :(showTo-1) ));

      items.hide().slice(showFrom, showTo).show();
    }
  });
});
```

HTML :

just add span

```
<span class="pagination-info"></span>
```

Comment: great! thanks so much sylwester. a quick update question. it works, however it displays from 0-9 and 10-19 when i toggel between the pages(1 and 2), but on render it displays fine. what would i need to change to make it display: (1-10) and (11-20). Thanks

Comment: actually it worked. i tried form the plunker you provided. Thanks so much.